# Command Not Found In shell/bash scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 14.10

I'm unable to find common commands in my script files which worked perfectly since a few days back.I have to give complete path for them now.

```
           /bin/mkdir "beta1"
           /usr/bin/npm install "$COMMAND"
```

which should be like :

```
           mkdir "beta1"
           npm install "$COMMAND"
```

I've even tried adding source ~/.profile in my script but nothing helps.

Comment: echo you $PATH, just to see

Comment: Check your PATH variable with `echo $PATH` and set it properly.

Comment: @Alper no, he should export this default path, what if he has custom useful entries ?

Comment: I can see my path by echo $PATH in terminal as :

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/sbin/node:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin

In Script as :

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/sbin/node:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin

Comment: Is the script run by yourself using the terminal or is it run by the "system" using cron/any-other-scheduler/any-other-application? Does the caller have the path also? Just try logging the path within your script to make sure the environment gets set up correctly.

Comment: @SebastianLange I'm running it using terminal. Its placed in ~/Documents/

Comment: Does your script use `PATH` as a variable name, which would overwrite the value it inherits from the shell?

Comment: Try to `echo $PATH` right after the hashbang, see if it gets altered in your script or before calling. By moving up the echo you may find the source of the error.

Comment: Does your $HOME value contain any space chars? Else to confirm that this is PATH issue, make a small script file with just `mkdir ./betaZ`(and chmod 755 that script). I bet that works. Then it means you are overwriting your PATH someplace in your installer script. So turn on `set -vx` and look for where PATH gets set. (maybe more than once). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of PATH as a variable name was the issue. I was overriding it at some point.

Answer (score 2):

If the path you posted in the comments is a `verbatim` **copy/paste** of your path, your problem is you have embedded NON-ASCII characters in your path. This is most likely due to having edited your path using an editor in windows (or a non-text editor e.g. OpenOffice) that has substituted a non-standard character for a regular ASCII value. Looking at a hexdump of your PATH shows the problem:

```
$ hexdump -C -n 233 pathprob.sh
00000000  23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 62  61 73 68 0a 0a 50 41 54  |#!/bin/bash..PAT|
00000010  48 3d 2f 75 73 72 2f 6c  6f 63 61 6c 2f 73 62 69  |H=/usr/local/sbi|
00000020  6e 3a 2f 75 73 72 2f 6c  6f 63 61 6c 2f 62 69 6e  |n:/usr/local/bin|
00000030  3a 2f 75 73 72 2f 73 62  69 6e 3a 2f 75 73 72 2f  |:/usr/sbin:/usr/|
00000040  62 69 6e 3a 2f 73 62 69  6e 3a 2f 62 69 6e 3a 2f  |bin:/sbin:/bin:/|
00000050  75 73 72 2f 67 61 6d 65  73 3a 2f 75 73 72 2f 6c  |usr/games:/usr/l|
00000060  6f 63 e2 80 8c e2 80 8b  61 6c 2f 67 61 6d 65 73  |oc......al/games|
00000070  3a 2f 75 73 72 2f 73 62  69 6e 2f 6e 6f 64 65 3a  |:/usr/sbin/node:|
00000080  2f 75 73 72 2f 6c 69 62  2f 6a 76 6d 2f 6a 61 76  |/usr/lib/jvm/jav|
00000090  61 2d 37 2d 6f 72 61 63  6c 65 2f 62 69 6e 3a 2f  |a-7-oracle/bin:/|
000000a0  75 73 72 2f 6c 69 62 2f  6a 76 6d 2f 6a 61 76 61  |usr/lib/jvm/java|
000000b0  2d 37 2d 6f 72 61 63 6c  65 e2 80 8c e2 80 8b 2f  |-7-oracle....../|
000000c0  64 62 2f 62 69 6e 3a 2f  75 73 72 2f 6c 69 62 2f  |db/bin:/usr/lib/|
000000d0  6a 76 6d 2f 6a 61 76 61  2d 37 2d 6f 72 61 63 6c  |jvm/java-7-oracl|
000000e0  65 2f 6a 72 65 2f 62 69  6e                       |e/jre/bin|
000000e9
```

Notice how `usr/loc......al/games` appears. There is a similar problem with `java-7-oracle......`. This effectively corrupts your `PATH` variable. The corrupting characters are the same in both places `e2 80 8c e2 80 8b`. They represent a `e2 80 8c` a `Unicode ⁌` and  `e2 80 8b` a `Unicode ⁋`.

The soluton -- copy your path to a text editor. Delete/replace `local/` with a new retyped `local/` and do the same thing for `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin`